# owner permissions not changing on Linux/Unix

Tags: centos, permissions

I have run a command and changed the group and owner for a directory but It is still showing under root user and group:

```
[xev@php56 datax]$ ll
total 25324
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     1426 Mar 15 14:15 nxew.sql
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     4096 Feb 27 16:51 older
[xev@php56 datax]$ sudo chown -R xev:xev older
[sudo] password for xev:
[xev@php56 datax]$ ll
total 25324
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     1426 Mar 15 14:15 nxew.sql
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     4096 Feb 27 16:51 older
```

Comment: Does the filesystem support POSIX ownership and permissions?

Comment: What is the output of `(until findmnt . ; do cd .. ; done)`?